# Typescript compiler error expected semi-colon with Angular 1.5 component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, components

I am getting an expected semi-colon error from TypeScript when trying to compile the following Angular component.

It seems fine to me but the error was only thrown when i added the `this.$routeConfig` array:

```
export class AppComponent implements ng.IComponentOptions {
    public template: string;
    public $routeConfig: Array<any>;
    constructor(){
        this.template = `<h1>Home</h1>
                        <ng-outlet></ng-outlet>`;
        this.$routeConfig: [{ 
            path: '/', 
            component: 'loginComponent', 
            name: 'Login', 
            useAsDefault: true
        }];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realised my 'school boy' error!

Should be `this.$routeConfig = [];`